# Hide image if taxonomy term is empty

Tags: php, taxonomy, terms

So I have a Country taxonomy with the country names as terms. The country names are represented by clickable flags (png images) on a map. Now I only want to show flags for terms that have countries in them, so what I need is simply to hide the flags representing empty terms.

I'm not a php developer, but here's an excerpt from the map's css:

```
<div class="mapCont">
<img class="mapAdjust" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/map-adjust.gif" />
    <img class="map" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/map.jpg" />
        <div class="flagSweden">
            <a href="<?php echo home_url();?>/country/sweden" alt="Sweden" title="Sweden">
            <img class="flag" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/flags/sweden-flag.png" /></a> <!-- Sweden -->
        </div>  <!-- /flagCont -->
        <div class="flagChina">
            <a href="<?php echo home_url();?>/country/china" alt="China" title="China">
            <img class="flag" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/flags/china-flag.png" /></a> <!-- China -->
        </div>  <!-- /flagCont -->
        <div class="flagBrazil">
            <a href="<?php echo home_url();?>/country/brazil" alt="Brazil" title="Brazil">
            <img class="flag" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/flags/brazil-flag.png" /></a> <!-- Brazil -->
```

etc...

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: generate your flags code dynamically by using `get_terms();` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of write manually the html code for your flags, you should create it using php and wordpress functions:

```
$countries = get_terms('country', array('hide_empty' => true) );
$exclude_terms = array('featured');

if ( ! empty($countries) && is_array($countries) ) { ?>

  <img class="mapAdjust" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/map-adjust.gif" />
  <img class="map" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/map.jpg" />

  <?php
    foreach ( $countries as $country ) {
      if ( ! empty($exclude_terms) && in_array($country->slug, $exclude_terms) ) continue;
      $name = esc_attr($country->name);
      $slug = $country->slug;
  ?>

    <div class="flag<?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $name); ?>">
      <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($country, 'country') ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>">
        <img class="flag" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/flags/<?php echo $slug; ?>-flag.png" />
      </a> <!-- <?php echo $name; ?> -->
    </div>  <!-- /flagCont -->

  <?php
  }
}
```

I've used only 2 functions:

- [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)
- [get_term_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link)

Comment: You genious! I more or less copied your code as is and it just worked. Thanks a lot my friend. Two small questions though: One term is not a country represented on the map, but a Featured term. How would I go about excluding that from the code? Also, as of now all flags link to the term page I'm currently visiting. How can I fix that? Thanks again!

Comment: One more thing. Some countries, like South Africa, consists of two words, which means the flag tries to get the class "flagSouth Africa". Is there a way to remove the space in case there is one?

Comment: **(1)** The featured term is from the same taxonomy. Its used to feature certain posts from all country terms. Some posts can and will belong to both the featured term and a country term. Since the featured term is not a country it shouldn't show up on the map though. **(2)** I want the flags to link to the respective country term. As of now if I'm on lets say the Brazilian term page, then all the flags are linking to the Brazilian term, not just the Brazil flag. **(3)** I used str_replace and it worked like a charm! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Exclusif **(1)** I've add the feature of exclude one or  more term. in the array `$exclude_terms = array('featured');` put all the terms slug you want to exclude. I've used 'featured' because I dont kno which is the sluf of your feature term. **(2)** That was just a littele bug, I forgot an `echo` on the code, now fixed. --- Try now the new code, and if it works for you, please, mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: It worked wonders. Everything is flawless now. Thanks once again friend.